# Ban all command not working for discord bot. (discord js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a ban all command for my bot and am having issues. When I try to use it, I get an error:

> DiscordAPTError: Missing Permissions

This is my code:

```
const { Client, Discord } = require("discord.js")
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  try {
    message.guild.members.cache.each(m => {
      m.ban();
  });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
  }
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "banall",
  desc: "Bans everyone",
}
```

Comment: this is API abuse.

Comment: Possible duplicate + depicts abuse of the discord API

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
let members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
members.forEach(member => {
    if (member.bannable) {
        member.ban().catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
    }
});
```

Also make sure your bot has the correct intents (configured in your js file) and permissions on the server (role perms)

Comment: When i try to use the command, nothing happens. No error, No banning, Nothing.
I tried to edit it a little, but still, either a random error or nothing.

Comment: Do you have all your intents configured correctly?

Comment: I am 98% sure that I do

Comment: Ok well add a `console.log(member);` to the forEach loop and see what it returns